# Fprintf doesnt write array to file

Tags: c, arrays, file, printing

I have a code which should read an array, write it to a binary and to a text file, then print the files. However, the fprintf function returns an error and i have no idea why. 
This is my code :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{ 
    FILE *f,*b;

    if (f=fopen("fis.txt","w+")==NULL) { 
        printf ("Error\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    if(b=fopen("binar.txt","w+b")==NULL) { 
        printf ("Error\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    float *v; int n;
    char s[1000];
    scanf("%d",&n);
    v=malloc(n*sizeof(float)); 

    int x,y;
    for (int i=0;i<=n;i++) { 
        scanf("%f",&v[i]);
        printf("%f",v[i]);

        x=fprintf(f,"%f",v[i]); 
        if (x<0) printf("err\n");

        y=fprintf(b,"%f",v[i]); 
        if (y<0) printf ("err2\n");
    }

    fgets(s,sizeof(s),f); 
    puts(s); 
    printf("\n");

    fgets(s,sizeof(s),b);
    puts(s);
    printf("\n");

    free(v);
    fclose(f);
    fclose(b);
}
```

Comment: Off by 1 error in your loop. Trying to scanf into `v[0]`, `v[1]`, ... `v[n-1]`, `v[n]`; but `v[n]` does not exist.

Comment: `int i=0;i<=n;i++` should be`int i=0;i<n;i++` writing 1 value out of array

Comment: Try `perror` to print the error reason (based on the value of `errno`); most standard library functions set `errno` on failure.

Comment: Thank you. I modified but it still doesnt work

Comment: You're writing text to the binary file.

Comment: You need to seek to the beginning of the file before you try to read it.

Comment: Also note that you are not writing any whitespace between the numbers in the text file, so reading them back may be somewhat difficult.

Comment: Well i cant even write to the file. The error i got with perror is : Invalid argument

Comment: I dont want to read the values back, only the text that the file contains. However, i cant get there since the writing doesnt work :/

Comment: warning `(b=fopen("binar.txt","w+b")==NULL)`must be `((b=fopen("binar.txt","w+b"))==NULL)`and same for other fopen, currently it is like if you have `(b=(fopen("binar.txt","w+b")==NULL))` no ?

Comment: I strongly recommend you compile with all warnings enabled, and treat any warnings as errors. I would expect most compilers to warn about the assignment bug. Admittedly the warning message may be a bit obscure, probably something like "conversion from integer to pointer", but it would at least point you to a line where something is wrong. And in that case the first thing to do would be to get rid of anything you are not absolutely sure about, which would hopefully include chaining multiple operators without parentheses.

Comment: Thank you, writing to the files finally worked. However i cannot print what they contain , the error is again, Invalid argument. I did modify everything you talked about.

Answer (score 3):

The main issue is how you're opening the files:

```
if (f=fopen("fis.txt","w+")==NULL) {
```

The equality operator `==` has higher precedence than the assignment operator `=`.  So first the result of `fopen` is compared to NULL, then the result of that comparison,  i.e. either 0 or 1, is assigned to `f`.  So `f` doesn't point to a valid location, and that is why your `fprintf` calls fail.  If you have warnings turned up on your compiler, it should have warned about assigning an integer to a pointer.

Add parenthesis to get the proper ordering:

```
if ((f=fopen("fis.txt","w+"))==NULL) {
```

And:

```
if ((b=fopen("binar.txt","w+b"))==NULL) {
```

Also, your loop condition is incorrect:

```
for (int i=0;i<=n;i++) {
```

The array `v` has `n` elements, meaning its indexes go from `0` to `n-1`, but you loop from `0` to `n`.  Change the loop condition to account for this:

```
for (int i=0;i<n;i++) {
```

You also need to call `rewind` on each file descriptor before reading back from them so that you can read what you just wrote:

```
rewind(f);
fgets(s,sizeof(s),f); 
puts(s); 
printf("\n");

rewind(b);
fgets(s,sizeof(s),b);
puts(s);
printf("\n");
```

Comment: agree, this is what I said about the fopen, it is very strange she doesn't see she even cannot open the input file

Comment: I did not get any error and i overlooked the parenthesis . Thank you.

Comment: @MaryPoppins Glad I could help.  Feel free to [accept this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) if you found it useful.